# Stumped redirecting from old url (with parameters) to new url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect or rewrite a url so that when someone goes to /members/**username**/directory/**category** it gets rewritten to /members/**username**/listings/?directory_type=**category**

Can anyone provide me with the proper code i can't seem to get it working

ideally it would be great if it redirects to the new URL 301 as technically the old url doesn't exist

i have tried about 10 different things found online but several havent worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post what you've tried so far? It would also be worth understanding if mod-rewrite is active and functioning as it should. Eg. can you test simple rewrites and they work.

Comment: In addition also make sure that you are testing with a fresh anonymous window. So that you don't fall for client side stored results of an earlier, different rewriting setup.